# Commit generated CMakeLists.txt in Git?

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I build the ROS project I'm working on, I have a generated `CMakeLists.txt` in my root folder that points to `/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake`. We already have it committed, but I don't think it should be, since it's generated every time I run `catkin_make`. What's the best practice for ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310173/commit-generated-cmakelists.txt-in-git?/) by [jinhkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38883/jinhkim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jinhkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38883/jinhkim/) on 2018-12-06**:
Yes, using `git` specifically. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indeed, you should not be tracking that file in Git. You should be counting on `catkin_make` or `catkin_init_workspace` to auto-generate that file.

Moreover, if you are tracking that file in Git it sounds to me like potentially the root of your Git repository is not in the right place. For ROS, nearly all Git repositories contain either a single package/metapackage, or a collection of packages bundled together with a metapackage that depends on all of the packages. An example of the first situation might be [usb_cam](https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam), where the Git repo is initialized in the package's root directory. For an example of the second situation, the [ros_tutorials Git repository](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials) has a metapackage called `ros_tutorials` that depends on `roscpp_tutorials`, `rospy_tutorials` and `turtlesim`, and the source code for all of those packages is also in the Git repo. Put another way, you should be running `git init` in either a package's root directory or in a directory containing a collection of packages. You should not be running `git init` in the `src/` directory of a workspace.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6